# What are the arguments in node js put request

Tags: node.js, mern

what are the arguments name called in the code below,

```
router.route("/admin/orders").get(isAuthenticationUser, authorizeRoles("admin"),getAllOrders);
```

can someone point it out like this:

```
map((element, index) => { /* … */ })
```

Answer (score 2):

Taking it from the [Express official docs](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#app.METHOD):.

The basic way to call handle http method is with the `app.METHOD` function (like, `app.get` for example), with this signature:

```
app.METHOD(path, callback [, callback ...])
```

Another way is how you show in your snippet, but using a [router](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#app.route). A router is used to narrow the scope of your handlers for a specific path (in your case, the path is `"/admin/orders"`).

The resutning object from calling `route(...)` is like:

```
router.METHOD(callback [, callback ...])
```

That means, all the three arguments (`isAuthenticationUser, authorizeRoles("admin"),getAllOrders`) are just variables/expressions that will resolve to callback functions. They will be executed one after the other in order when your http request comes. Most probable, judging by their names, the first two will try to authenticate and authorize the user, but if not possible, they will short-circuit and return the call, not even getting into the third callback.

You can also see more details in the [Routing Guide](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html).